# Cannot find where I made a mistake

Tags: errors, texlipse

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}

\center{\huge{\emph{Calcul théorique de la propulsion éléctromagnetique de
l'aimant}}}

\null\null\null

\raggedright{\LARGE Constantes ``modifiables''}

\null

{\emph Rayon des spires}\tab \tab \tab \tab \textbf{D}

{\emph Nombre de spire}\tab \tab \tab \tab \textbf{N}

{\emph Tension du générateur}\tab \tab \tab \textbf{$\mu$}

{\emph Capacité du condensateur}\tab \tab \textbf{C}

{\emph Arètes du tore}\tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \textbf{L}

{\emph Masse du tore}\tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \textbf{m}

\null

{\LARGE Variables}

\null

{\emph Vitesse de tore}\tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \textbf{v(t)}

{\emph Tension du condensateur}\tab \tab \tab \textbf{u(t)}

{\emph Intensité}\tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \textbf{i(t)}

{\emph Champ magnétique}\tab \tab \tab \tab \textbf{$\vec{B}$}

{\emph Potentiel vecteur}\tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \textbf{$\vec{A}$}

{\emph Densité de courant dans le tore}\tab \tab \textbf{$\vec{j}$}

\null

{\LARGE Equations}

\null

{\fbox{\textbf{$m\frac{dv}{dt}=-mg+\iiint_{tore-en-mouvement}(\vec{j}\times\vec{B})\cdot\vec{e_z}d\tau$}}}

\null

\null

{\textbf{$i=-C\frac{du}{dt}$}}

\null

\null

{\textbf{$u=Ri+\iint_{N-spires}\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{S}$}}

\null

\null

{\textbf{$\vec{j}=\gamma(\vec{v}\times\vec{B}-\frac{\partial
\vec{A}}{\partial t})$}}

\null

\null

{\textbf{$\vec{A}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\iiint_{tore-en-mouvement}\frac{\vec{j}}{PM}\cdot
d\tau + \frac{\mu_0 Ni}{4\pi}\int\frac{d\vec{r}}{PM}$}}

\null

\null

{\textbf{$\vec{B}=rot\vec{A}$}}

\end{document}
```

I have tested the individual lines at:

http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor

They are giving the desired results. However the entire code compiled together gives the following error on TeXlipse:

```
Emergency stop. \end{document} (followed by: )
```

Can't figure out the mistake I have made.

Sorry I've just started off with LATEX hence my way of writing the document may seem to be bizarre.

Comment: That compiles without a problem for me. I pasted it into the [WriteLateX](https://www.writelatex.com/) site as well and it compiles there, also.

Comment: It works for me too. By the way, you write the document in an impractical way.

Comment: A mistake? A? Near everything should be rewritten. BTW: I have compiled your document with no problem.

Comment: Cant see the forest from the trees

Comment: Compiles without a problem for me, too, but the results are wildly different from what you presumably expect.  For example, you have things like `\textbf{<maths>}` -- maths isn't affected by `\textbf` (it affects _text_); you use something other than ascii for input, but don't load an input encoding; you use `\center` as a command (it's part of an environment and won't work as you want).  i've not quite understood your use of \null. and that's for starters.  do you have a latex primer of any sort? -- i suggest you read it a bit.

Comment: Try deleting the `.aux` file and compiling again.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I have started using LATEX recently. Sorry for this awkward style of writing the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to proceed with something like this, which is (in my opinion) more  `\LaTeX`y and compiles fine for me. If you *really* need the italic title and sections, this can probably be changed, I just went with the defaults.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{Calcul théorique de la propulsion éléctromagnetique de l'aimant}
\author{Lawrence}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Constantes ``modifiables''}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
        \toprule
        Rayon des spires & \(D\)\\
        Nombre de spire & \(N\)\\
        Tension du générateur & \(\mu\)\\
        Capacité du condensateur & \(C\)\\
        Arètes du tore & \(L\)\\
        Masse du tore & \(m\)\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section*{Variables}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
        \toprule
        Vitesse de tore & \(v(t)\)\\
        Tension du condensateur & \(u(t)\)\\
        Intensité & \(i(t)\)\\
        Champ magnétique & \(\vec{B}\)\\
        Potentiel vecteur & \(\vec{A}\)\\
        Densité de courant dans le tore & \(\vec{j}\)\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section*{Equations}
\begin{equation}
    \boxed{
        m \frac{dv}{dt} = -mg + \iiint_{\textrm{tore-en-mouvement}} (\vec{j} \times \vec{B}) \cdot \vec{e_z}d\tau
    }
    \label{m}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    i = -C \frac{du}{dt}
    \label{i}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    u = Ri + \iint_{N-spires} \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{S}
    \label{u}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \vec{j} = \gamma \left( \vec{v} \times \vec{B} - \frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t} \right)
    \label{j}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \vec{A} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \iiint_{tore-en-mouvement} \frac{\vec{j}}{PM} \cdot d\tau + \frac{\mu_0 Ni}{4\pi} \int\frac{d\vec{r}}{PM}
    \label{A}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \vec{B} = rot\vec{A}
    \label{B}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the trouble to correct the document. I have tried your code and it works perfectly for me :-)

Comment: @Lawrence Please also take a while to familiarize yourself with some common conventions and syntax. This will help you work on your document later with fewer problems. There are numerous guides on the internet for this, and I'll leave it up to someone more experienced to suggest one (or you could find one yourself :) )